# Which browsers remove tap delay if meta viewport is used

Tags: html, responsive-design, mobile-safari, microsoft-edge

Which browsers currently remove tap delay on mobile if I use this meta ?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I know that **Chrome for Android** and **Firefox for Android** remove delay, but what about other browsers **EDGE** and **Webkit**(**Safari**) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webkit JUST removed this [several days ago](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=149854), so it isn't in any shipped browsers. Edge has supported this from the beginning.